# Select column from separate tables based on data from first table's column

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to select a data from a seperate table based on the first query.

[Appointment Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSQxv.png)

[Treatment Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpiqE.png)

I have a text box for the user to enter in their patientID and when the Search button is pressed, the application will query the database for the patient's ID number and display the treatment names under that Name table on the left and the application will also search for the relevant cost depending on the treatments administered and display it on the right.
I am only able to display one query at the time on the application and I have no idea why it cant run both queries.

```
private void button_SearchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
                // when this is clicked total costs loads
                //by adding all of the costs column
    try{
    String str = field_PatientNumber.getText();
    int f = Integer.parseInt(str);
    String sql = "SELECT TreatmentName FROM Appointment WHERE PatientID='"+ f +"'";
    String sql2 = "SELECT Cost FROM Treatment WHERE Name IN (SELECT TreatmentName FROM Appointment WHERE PatientID='"+ f +"')";
    //String treatmentName = rs.getString("TreatmentName");

    //System.out.println(treatmentName);
    //String sql2 = "SELECT Cost FROM Treatment where Name='"+ treatmentName +"'";
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    rs2 = stmt.executeQuery(sql2);
    stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);       
    stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql2);
    jTableName.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    jTableCost.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs2));

    double s=0;
        for(int i=0;i<jTableCost.getRowCount();i++){
        String d= jTableCost.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
        double d1=Double.parseDouble(d);
        s+=d1;
        }

        String totalCost = String.valueOf(s);
        field_TotalCosts.setText(totalCost);

    }
    catch(Exception e){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's the GUI for the application(I can't post more than 2 links)

https://gyazo.com/f5fb64ef1843cd79f1858e829674b2fe

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding one your variables.

```
stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);       
stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql2);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html Shows an example, but during this case they are separated-  Quote:

```
...
updateSales = con.prepareStatement(updateString);
updateTotal = con.prepareStatement(updateStatement);
```

In fact looking at this closer again, you have executed your statements before actually preparing them.